# Send a SIGINT to a daemonized process

Tags: c++, linux, unix, signals, posix

I wrote a c++ code that daemonizes itself..

it has a signal handler for a SIGINT signal

Obviously it does not get the signal when running on the shell as it's daemonized.

How do I send the signal?

Thanks

Comment: I meant with using ctrl+c

Comment: ctrl+c goes to the foreground process.

Comment: trap SIGINT in the foreground process and forward it to the other process.

Comment: The whole purpose of daemonization is to have the process run forever, and in particular be insensitive to Ctrl-C on the terminal. You could want to add a program argument to avoid calling `daemon(3)`

Answer (score 3):

You can not send a `SIGINT` to a daemonized process using `Ctrl-C`.
What you need to do is to find a process id (PID) using `ps` command and use `kill -INT <pid>` to send the signal.

Answer (score 1):

killall process name -signal number

```
killall helloworld -2
```

will send SIGINT to helloworld process

Comment: Thanks but I'm familiar with this...I was looking more towards the use of ctrl+c and not with typing a command

Answer (score 1):

Locate its process identifier using `ps`, then send the SIGINT signal via `kill -INT PID`.